# Unable to run Java program in Eclipse Juno 4.2

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I reinstall my Eclipse environment every year when the new version is released. The most recent release - Juno - however, does not work as expected.

Currently, when I try running demos from Oracle, for example, it asks me to select an Ant file to run before compiling. After creating a blank Ant file to bypass the requirement (which I thought was rather dumb, since I don't think TDD is something that should be forced on people), it still refused to run, saying the "Selection could not be launched."

I understand that Juno is an update from the 3.x track to the 4.x track, but this seems a little ridiculous to me. What can or should I do so I can get Eclipse back up and running again?

Just to clarify:

- All files in question are on my Eclipse workspace path
- I don't do much in the way of Java development, though I know I'll need to do so soon. Hence, my unfamiliarity with the most recent version of Eclipse.
- I would like to run my files & projects without Ant files. I know it has something to do with Run configs, but I don't know how to change them.

Comment: Please post what Oracle demo you are trying to run and the Ant file you created.

Comment: I'm running FrameDemo.java and I just used a blank Ant file. However, I'd much rather just be able to run without an Ant file.

Comment: Which Juno did you download?  Is it the same one as you dowloaded for Indigo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did to run the demo from Eclipse Juno:

1. Downloaded the project from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/zipfiles/components-FrameDemoProject.zip (if this is not the correct demo, then please provide the link you're using)
2. Unzipped it to my projects directory (not my workspace), so that you have:

   PROJECTS_DIR/components-FrameDemoProject/src

   PROJECTS_DIR/components-FrameDemoProject/nbproject

   PROJECTS_DIR/components-FrameDemoProject/build.xml
3. From Eclipse, File > New > Java Project
4. List item Uncheck `Use default location` and navigate to `<PROJECTS_DIR>/components-FrameDemoProject`
5. Hit `Finish`
6. Drill down to `src/components/FrameDemo.java`
7. Right-click on `FrameDemo.java` and select `Run As` > `Java Application`

Let me know if any of these steps give you trouble.

Comment: Not sure why, but hovering over `Run As...` presented no options - at least none that I could click. It worked out after following your instructions, though, and Eclipse no longer gives me any issues when setting up a new project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at you project properties and select the Builders entry. Do you see an `Ant Builder` entry? Try to select or create a `Java Builder` entry instead.

I just created a new Java Project in Juno and added the `FrameDemo.java` source. In my case, the `Java Builder` was selected as the default for this new project.